# Problem in Maya with a function and run itself again (deleteUI and showWindow)

Tags: python, maya

I have this simple UI window, I want to click a button to detect if the UI window exist or not, if so, delete it first, and re-start the UI (cmds.showWindow) again. However, sometimes this code would just delete the UI without showing the window again.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

testWin = 'testWin'

def ui():
    if cmds.window(testWin, query = True, exists = True):
        cmds.deleteUI(testWin)
    
    cmds.window(testWin, widthHeight=(200, 55) )
    cmds.columnLayout()
    cmds.button(label= 'Run AGAIN', c = deleteWin)
    cmds.setParent('..')
    cmds.showWindow( testWin )
    

def deleteWin(*args):
    ui()
    
ui()
```

It seems random as well, sometimes after the first click, sometimes after the third click..
Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: I sometimes had problems if I execute a script which deletes an ui while the script is still running. Seems that Maya does not like actions like that. I recommend to use a layout and delete and rebuild the layout inside a window.

Comment: deleting a ui can have some delay issue, that why autodesk recommand sometimes to use evalDeferred commad